# Laravel 5.8: Proper use of Request at Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have added this simple method for updating a form that has only one input of type `file`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
public function update(Request $request, News $news)
    {
        $feature_image = $request->file('nws_feature_image');
        dd($feature_image);
        return redirect(route('news.index'));
    }
```

But I get this error:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::file()**

Then I tried replacing the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` with `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` but got this error:

**Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() should not be called statically**

Then I tried adding `use Request;` and got this error:

**use Request; but got Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::file()**

So what is the proper way of using `Request` in Laravel 5.8 ?

Comment: Where did you use this `Illuminate\Http\Request::get() `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may retrieve uploaded files from an Illuminate\Http\Request instance using the file method

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$file = $request->file('nws_feature_image');
```

Comment: Thats correct but I get `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() should not be called statically` then..

Comment: @tejoslaeslio Your form should be add `enctype= multipart/form-data` Like <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Yes it has `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. But when I add `Illuminate\Http\Request;` it works properly but it returns this error: `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::get() should not be called statically`

Comment: @tejoslaeslio Please show your blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way hope this will help you

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//To check please print your **Request**
//print_r($request->all());exit();

$file = $request->file('nws_feature_image');//to get your image file

Thanks